# How to make this DOS plot more smooth and add more points around Fermi level?

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, density-of-states, dos

I have calculated and plotted the DOS for a doped monolayer 3x3x1 supercell. I want to make the plot more smooth and add more points around Fermi level.
Knowing that these are my settings for the INCAR :

```
NCORE = 6
KPAR = 5
# DOS
ICHARG = 11
IBRION = -1
NSW = 0
LORBIT = 11
NEDOS = 2001

#Electronic Relaxation:
ENCUT = 600 eV
EDIFF = 1.0E-6
PREC = Accurate
LREAL = .FALSE.
ALGO = Normal
ADDGRID=.TRUE.

#Relaxation:
ISMEAR = -5
#SIGMA = 0.05
EDIFFG = -0.01
GGA COMPAT = .FALSE.

# Magnetism:
ISPIN= 2
MAGMOM = 7*0.0 18*0.0 2*5.0
LASPH = .TRUE.
LMAXMIX = 4
VOSKOWN = 1

#Mixer
AMIX     = 0.2
BMIX     = 0.00001
AMIX_MAG = 0.8
BMIX_MAG = 0.00001
```

And KPOINTS :

```
15x15x1
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To smooth the curve, you need to change (increase) the value of `NEDOS` as it represents the number of grid points to plot ([source](https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/NEDOS)).

As the DOS plot is done using a homogeneous grid, if you want the curve more defined around the Fermi level, you need to narrow the energy interval around it defining the values of `EMIN` and `EMAX` (look for the definition of [EMIN](https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/EMIN) and [EMAX](https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/EMAX)) .

Comment: By EMIN and EMAX do they mean the interval in the horizontal axis ?

Comment: Yes, the interval in the x axis. You can use something like this: define $\epsilon$, and then $EMIN=FERMI_{level} - \epsilon$ and $EMAX=FERMI_{level} + \epsilon$.

Comment: Thank you very much sir.